# Want to write text with keyboardstyle sys.stdout.write(char) to Tkinter interface

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use the `main()` to create the text and display it in a tkinter widget but I don't know how to make it.

```
import sys, time, os, random
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter import * 

filepath = "file.txt"

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg=color_black)
    
def main():
    file = open('file.txt', "r")
    for line in file:
        message = line
        for char in message:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            my_label.config(text=char)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(0,0.05))
    file.close()

global my_label
my_label = Label(root, text="")
my_label.pack(pady=10)

main()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could create a `tkinter.Text` widget and repeatedly call its `insert()` method to add successive lines of output to it.

Comment: output.insert(INSERT,char)
output.update_idletasks()

this lines work good but when a endline come in from the text file, the program stop

Comment: Seems like you should be using `output.insert(END,char)`. The call to `update_idletasks()` is needed because you're using `time.sleep()`. Use the universal [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method instead and you wouldn't need it.